# Creating a symbolic link in Sites directory

Tags: macos, apache2

I have a file in my `~/Sites` directory that works fine when I browse to it through `coderama.local/~coderama/index2.php`

Now I want to get tricky and move my `index2.php` file to somewhere else on my system, so I do this by creating a symbolic link. However, when I try to access `coderama.local/~coderama/index2.php` I now get the following error.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!

> #### Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /~coderama/index2.php on this server.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

That's a configurable Apache option.  It appears that by default on Macs (and probably most installations) Apache is configured to not follow symbolic links.  I'm guessing (as others mention above) that it's for security purposes.

But it can be really convenient at times to enable following of symbolic links, particularly during development of certain kinds of apps.  What you need to do is 1) change the Apache configuration to allow the following of symbolic links, and then 2) restart Apache.

The configuration step is performed as follows:

a) cd /etc/apache2   (this is where Apache's configuration files are by default on a Mac)

b) you'll see a couple of directories here.  One is called users

c) cd users

d) ls should reveal a .conf file with your login name (*login*.conf)  I'm "marvo" so mine is named "marvo.conf"

e) Edit this file (I use vi) -- but you have to do it using sudo:

```
sudo vi marvo.conf
```

f) You'll see something like

```
<Directory "/Users/marvo/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews 
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

g) Add the "FollowSymLinks" option so that the second line of that .conf file looks like:

```
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
```

(You can find other configuration options out there on the 'net.  I found this page:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory )

h) Save the file.

Now you have to restart Apache so that it picks up the configuration change.  Googling around a bit, I found that this is most easily done from the command line with the following command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

(Found that at http://mcapewell.wordpress.com/2006/09/22/restart-apache-in-mac-os-x/ )

Now that symbolic link should work just fine on your Sites pages.

Comment: also you can restart the apache using just: **sudo apachectl restart**.

Comment: Read the next answer from agarie for the right info. On Mountain Lion, at least, FollowSYmLinks *is* configured by default, but if you've got things in Documents, Dropbox, etc. that you're linking to, you'll need to add a+rx permissions to those directories they're a-rx by default.

Comment: I originally wrote this for Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 56):

Had the same issue. Unfortunately, Marvo's answer wasn't enough.

The problem lies with the permissions set on every folder in the path, starting from `~/`. The directories needs the `execute` flag set to be able to recurse the directory tree. So, in my case, I symlinked a theme folder from  `~/Dropbox/projects/theme` to a wordpress install on `~/Site/wordpress`.

The answer was:

```
chmod a+x ~/Dropbox/
chmod a+rx ~/Dropbox/projects
```

This is an old issue, but if anyone reaches this page, it might be useful. :)

Comment: Had much the same issue, and had only changed permissions on ~/Dropbox/folder not on ~/Dropbox itself. I should know this by now! Thanks.

Comment: You know, I had to follow my own instructions here again on a new Mac.  And yep, had to set the permissions.  It's kind of a separate issue than configuring Apache to follow symbolic links, but a useful reminder just the same.

Comment: cheers, kinda funny that in the name of security you have to give public access to your home folder!

Comment: If you really got "careful" about it all, you could probably use one of the same groups as the webserver, and limit access to just the webserver group rather than give it to everyone.  But on a development machine like mine, I don't care that much.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a security issue (also suggested by Matt)

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1771399

Comment: This worked for me when I arrived at this question through Google.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, chmod a+rx on the whole path of the linked folder helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember the specific reason why, but it doesn't work. It's a security issue. You can use XAMPP http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html or MAMP http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marvo's answer. What helped me was to **Change the  permission on Documents** folder:

```
cd ~
chmod a+rx Documents/
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have a  directive in your httpd-vhosts.conf

Otherwise you get the same '403 forbidden in the browser', with 'the client denied by server configuration in the error log.